# Account with NatWest compromised. Will I get a refund?

Tags: bank-account, fraud, phishing

Someone from Cambodia has managed to withdraw over £500 from my account about 36 hours ago. I just found out now and been on the phone to Natwest fraud team. They say they will get back to me within 5 days.

I'm worried that they will try to catch me out on something so they don't need to give me a refund. However, I still have my card, I don't store my PIN any other places than in my head, I haven't given my details to ANYONE ever.

I don't understand how it happened in the first place, but checking my PC for trojans etc as it seems like the only logical explanation to this.

So my question is, has anyone tried something similar? If you have did you ever get a refund?

**UPDATE:** I got a full refund from NatWest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The card usually comes with an insurance and protects you if you have reported a fraud with a few days of its happening. Mostly its a 60 or a 90 day reporting period. The refund though would only arrive after the completion of full investigation and this might take some time.

Do make sure that everything you do with the bank from here on is on paper or atleast in written. Ask them for a time frame by which this case would be clarified and boy make them write it on a mail or a bank letterhead. Make sure you have the name of the person dealing on the case. If they don't give you any answer or money within the given timeframe launch a complaint on the Financial Ombudsman Service website and they will make take care of it from there.

http://www.financial-ombudsman.org.uk

Comment: Thank you Bhavin. Seems like I got quite a few options, but the bank should give me refund like you're stating.

Comment: I faced a similar problem while I was in UK with HSBC. I faced with a lot of trouble those days since I didnt make a written complain. The reason why I am asking you to get everything in written from the bank. Then my college tutor who was an ex-banker told be to make a formal complain and ask them to reply in written and if they dont make a complain to FOS which I did. I not only got my 2000 GBP back but also received another 2000 to take the complaint back from FOS.